# Looping through lists of files with bash - syntax error

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, snakemake

I've been trying to loop trough lists of files and apply an operation on them depending on their number. I first tried using the `ls` command, but the output is not a list:

```
data="data2/Scerevisiae-Pho4/"
results="results3/"
samples=( "GSM730517" "GSM730528" )

if [ ! -d $results ]
then
    mkdir $results
fi
for sam in ${samples[@]}
do
    if [ ! -d $results$sam ]
    then
        mkdir $results$sam
    fi
    echo -e "Reading $sam directory $data$sam... \n"
    files=$(ls $data$sam)
    echo ${files[0]}
done
```

outputs

```
echo ${files[@]}
    SRR217304.sra SRR217305.sra
echo ${files[0]}
    SRR217304.sra SRR217305.sra
```

I tried this different syntax:

```
files=($data$sam/*)
```

It worked fine locally, but then I used this as shell code into a [snakemake](https://bitbucket.org/johanneskoester/snakemake/wiki/Home) workflow, and then it throws a syntax error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I'm guessing it's a problem with the bash interpreter? Any clue how else I could loop through these files ?

Thanks

Edit:
I've also tried

```
 files=$data$sam/*
```

which outputs

```
echo ${files[0]}
data2/Scerevisiae-Pho4/GSM730517/*
```

Comment: Do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script?

Comment: You don't even need `files` variable. Just use: `echo "$data$sam"/* `

Comment: I need a variable cause I need to count the files in each directory, and then loop & merge them if several.

Comment: John, the thing is I don't exactly use a script file, I'm running the code in a snakemake workflow.

Comment: That error is because snakemake (whatever that is) is running the script with `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`. A proper shebang line might fix the problem or you might need to manually run your script somehow to use `/bin/bash` instead.

Comment: Note that snakemake automatically creates the directories when needed (as documented in step 3 of the tutorial: http://snakemake.bitbucket.org/snakemake-tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all these checks. You can use `mkdir -p` to create a directory path if it doesn't exist already.  Also you don't need to use arrays at all

```
for d in GSM730517 GSM730528;
do p=results3/$d; 
  mkdir -p $p;
  for f in $p/*; 
  do echo $f; 
  done;
done;
```

should iterate over all existing files, replace echo with your call.